# DRF and React authentication with djoser

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I have some problems with the login in Django-Djoser!
I used Django Djoser in api login.
 `path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken'))`
Changed URLs in auth context and in login js, however it doesn't work.

[authcontext.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzgw1.png)

and

[login.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aiIc.png)

Signup is working but the login didn't open the site!
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please provide your code samples as `text formatted as code` to make it easier for others to duplicate the examples.